# Spring prototype or provider from Java EE

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have a class

```
public class Test {

   @Autowired
   private Testing abc;

   public Testing getTesting() {
     return abc;
   }

}

@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class Testing {

   private int i;
}
```

Everytime I manually create class Test using the autowire capable bean factory, i expect an instance of Testing to be created.

However today i was introduced to a new concept of javax.inject.Provider

```
public class Test {

   @Autowired
   private Provider<Testing> abc;

   public Testing getTesting() {
     return abc.get();
   }
}



@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class Testing {

   private int i;

   //transactional methods
}
```

What benefit does it provides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - retrieving multiple instances.
> - lazy or optional retrieval of an instance.
> - breaking circular dependencies.
> - abstracting scope so you can look up an instance in a smaller scope from an instance in a containing scope.

From [Java EE Documentation:Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html)

**UPDATE:**
[Java EE Documentation: Inject Annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) discusses how circular dependencies in classes can be broken using `Provider`.

> A conservative injector might detect the circular dependency at build
>   time and generate an error, at which point the programmer could break
>   the circular dependency by injecting Provider or Provider
>   instead of A or B respectively.

Comment: but is it really useful if i will always need an instance?.. im asking as im having a conversation with a developer on this topic, hes trying to convince me provider is the better approach?.. ic ant see the difference in the example above.

Comment: Updated the answer to include a link and description that might be helpful to you. I am not an expert of this subject matter. So cannot comment on the specifics. But looking at the present example (not much complicated) seems that using any would be equal.